# Visual studio 2010: limiting the number of editor tabs

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, resharper

Visual studio doesn't appear to limit the number of opened editor tabs.
I'm using ReSharper and at a certain number of opened editor tabs things get really slow. So I have to keep track of opened tabs and periodically close old ones.
It would be cool if I could set a limit so that it would close old tabs when the limit is reached.

Is there a setting in VS / ReSharper or any VS addons that can help to achieve this?

Comment: Probably not too helpful, but I find resharper unbearable (even on my quad xeon with 12Gb of RAM) due to things like this so I removed it and use the Productivity Power Tools instead: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm trying to solve this with a primitive addin at the moment. Seems to be working fine. Still testing it.

```
    public void OnConnection(object application, ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst, ref Array custom)
    {

        _applicationObject = (DTE2)application;

        _applicationObject.Events.WindowEvents.WindowCreated += 
        window =>
        {
            if (window.Document != null)
            {
                documentWindows.AddFirst(window);
                if(documentWindows.Count > 7)
                {
                    Window lastWindow = documentWindows.Last.Value;
                    documentWindows.Remove(lastWindow);
                    lastWindow.Close(vsSaveChanges.vsSaveChangesYes);
                }
            }
        };

        _applicationObject.Events.WindowEvents.WindowClosing +=
            window =>
                {
                if(window.Document != null)
                {
                    documentWindows.Remove(window);
                }
                };
    }
```

Comment: Very interesting. A shame that it's not complete, how do you get 'documentWindows' please ? As an IntelliJ user and newcomer on Visual Studio I really miss this functionnality (among others :) )... Thanks by advance.

Comment: documentWindows is just a list of windows I maintain, it is all in the code above except the field definition. All my code for the adding except the windows list definition is above. Everything else is the standard boilerplate code generated when you create a VS adding project in VS.

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=davemckeown.TidyTabs